# How to track how many calls to a function my state lasts for?

Tags: javascript, function

I need to create a code that can keep track of the number of states for images. So, when a state changes, I can tell how many time units that particular state lasts for.

Here are some of my states

a. On for 5–6 time units = Dot

b. On for ≥ 7 time units = Dash

Do I use console.time()? Or something similar? 
Any starting pointers will be greatly appreciated.

```
// Start timing now
console.time("state1");

for ()
output ;

//  stop timing.
console.timeEnd("state1");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to count it, but if you want seconds here is an example, easily adjustable to any other time unit.

```
// Start counting time
var startTime = new Date();

// State 1

// wait till 5 seconds passed
while ((new Date() - startTime) / 1000 < 5);

// State 2


// wait till 7 seconds passed
while ((new Date() - startTime) / 1000 < 7);

// State 3
```